# notification doesn't show up only the vibrations work

Tags: android, kotlin

I have make notification fun outside the override onCreat fun 
when i test the app i got the notifications but it doesn't show up, i only get vibration on my phone 
while when i try the same code in an individual project just to check the notification fun it works correctly 
and when i try to move the fun of notifications inside the onCreat fun and same problem

i tried to put the fun inside or outside the override fun but its not working

```
   fun notifyMe(){

           notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

           val intent = Intent(this@MapsActivity, LauncherActivity::class.java)
           val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this@MapsActivity,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)



           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
               notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId,description,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
               notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
               notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
               notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
               notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

               buildder = Notification.Builder(this@MapsActivity,channelId)
                   .setContentTitle("NEAR")
                   .setContentText("YOU ARE NEAR ")
                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)
                   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this@MapsActivity.resources,R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


           }else{
               buildder = Notification.Builder(this@MapsActivity)
                   .setContentTitle("Distinatios")
                   .setContentText("YOU ARE near ")
                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)
                   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this@MapsActivity.resources,R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           }
           notificationManager.notify(1234,buildder.build())
       }
```

i expect to get simple notification 
now i got only the vibration of the notification

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to simplify this by using `NotificationCompact.Builder` and let it handle making your notification compatible with different OS versions. In my application, I also included `setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)` on the builder call. If those don't work, I would try commenting out `.setLargeIcon(...)` just to ensure that it isn't some issue with parsing the image.

Hope it helps!